# Multithreaded Java job deadlock on DB insert

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, oracle11g, deadlock

I am experiencing deadlock when running newly implemented job. I'll try to insert all minimum relevant parts of the code

**Job**

```
    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> BLOCKING_QUEUE = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    final ThreadPoolExecutor EXECUTOR = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 60, TimeUnit.HOURS, BLOCKING_QUEUE, new BlockWhenQueueFull());

    protected void doExecute() {
        records = service.getBatchRecordsToProcess(batchSize); // Load 500 records from DB by main thread
            for (Record record: records) {
                EXECUTOR.execute(() -> { // Take thread out of pool and make it process the record
                    service.processRecord(record);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    
    class BlockWhenQueueFull implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200); // If all threads are busy then put main thread to sleep and after 200 ms try once again
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                LOGGER.debug(interruptedException.getMessage(), interruptedException);
            }
            executor.execute(r);
        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
    public List<Record> getBatchRecordsToProcess(int batchSize) {
        return dao.getRecordsToProcess(batchSize);
    }
    

    public void processRecord(Record record) {
        processContent(record);
        writeToFs(record);
        markAsProcessed(record);
    }
    
    public void processContent(Record record) {
        // business logic
        NewRecord newRecord = new NewRecord(record);
        dao.insertNewRecord(newRecord);
    }
    
    private synchronized void writeToFs(Record record) throws IOException {
        // Create folders and files on FS and write there contents
    }
    
    private void markAsProcessed(Record record) {
        dao.markRecordAsProcessed(record);
    }
```

**DAO**

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Record> getRecordsToProcess(int batchSize) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_BATCH,
                new Object[]{batchSize},
                new RecordMapper());
    }

    @Transactional
    public void insertNewRecord(NewRecord newRecord) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                INSERT_NEW_RECORD,
                newRecord.getDate(),
                // values
        );
    }

    @Transactional
    public void markRecordAsProcessed(Record record) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_PROCESSED, record.getId());
    }
```

**Thread Dump**

First state applies for all 10 Threads.

```
"pool-2-thread-10@8925" prio=5 tid=0x44 nid=NA waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
     waiting for main@1 to release lock on <0x27c9> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
     ...
     at com.dao.NewRecordDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec63bd65.insertContent(<generated>:-1)
     

"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-1)
      at com.job.BlockWhenQueueFull.rejectedExecution(Job.java:130) *pointing to Thread.sleep(200);
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
          at com.job.BlockWhenQueueFull.rejectedExecution(Job.java:134) *pointing to executor.execute(r);
```

After the execution the job processes usually couple thousands of records and gets stuck - the main Thread just waits via RejectedExecutionHandler because all worker Threads are stuck. It looks like the worker threads are locked on `newRecordDao.insertContent(newRecord);` but the table does not have any foreign keys and no table is referencing columns in this table. Index is just on PK.

The question is - Is it possible to get a deadlock on Oracle table when multiple threads are concurrently inserting data (NewRecords), but no reads / updates are performed on this table? The table does not have generated PK - records are inserted with id in a random order (source table has tens of million of records so I do not want to perform costly ordering because of performance). Isolation level appears to be READ COMMITTED.

Is it required for method which writes onto filesystem (tmpfs / xfs) to be synchronized?

Initially I thought it would be problem of synced method for writing to filesystem but if I get the Thread Dump right it is an issue with insert into DB. I have no idea why should the DB inserts be the problem in this case.

Comment: First, I would check the record it is getting stuck on. Is it always in the same place, or is there anything unusual about the data in the stuck insert that might cause a SQL error if not correctly handled? 

I would also check system-level things: have you run out of redo log space or UNDO tablespace capacity and need to commit your transactions, or TEMP tablespace capacity? Anything that would cause the system to effectively hang until you commit or rollback your transactions?

Comment: From the Stacktrace, I see that the worker threads are waiting on the main thread to release a lock. What lock is that? Is the main thread acquiring any locks anywhere? Oracle would not get into deadlocks in your case (as you are only inserting new rows)